# Should I cancel my UK visa application if it was made too early?

Tags: visas, uk, applications

I made an online application to get a Standard UK visa (from outside of the UK). However, I made it too soon, 3 months and 15 days before the travel date. I read that, in this case, my visa will be refused. I'm not sure about this, but I'm thinking of cancelling it, and waiting until just 3 months before my trip, then doing a new application.

I already have an appointment, but I haven't paid for anything. I stated in my application that I'll pay on the day of my appointment at the Centre.

- Is this possible?
- Is it the best solution?
- Will I be able to do this without paying for anything?
- Will this affect the new application?

Comment: Can you reschedule it by three weeks?

Comment: Yes, I think I can. Do you think that would solve the problem? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Reschedule the appointment by three weeks. That should solve the problem. In your case you haven't already paid. If you had already paid you would be able to ask for a refund.

Per [VFS Global FAQ](http://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/UAE/frequently_asked_questions.html)

> **What should I do if I cannot attend the visa application centre on the appointed date?**
>
> If you cannot attend the visa application centre on the appointed
>   date, you would need to cancel your appointment and apply for a full
>   refund. Please refer to terms and conditions and refund policy.
>   Refunds are at the sole discretion of VFS Global and will be in line
>   with the refund policy.

Comment: This appears to be speculation. Do you have any references to offer in support?